# IE10 canvas performance better than Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, canvas

I'm drawing some lines and arrows, sometimes over a hundred on the screen at once, and for some reason IE10 is outperforming Chrome here. If I do not draw the arrows, the speed is fairly similar. So, I've deduced it is something with how IE10 renders lines vs. how Chrome renders lines.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be or any canvas tips that might speed up Chrome?

Here is the part that, when commented out, makes Chrome much faster but doesn't appear to really affect IE10 at all:

```
        var risePercent2 = runPercent;
        var runPercent2 = -risePercent;
        var newX = targetX - (runPercent * (targetSize + arrowLength));
        var newY = targetY - (risePercent * (targetSize + arrowLength));
        context.moveTo(
            newX + (runPercent2 * arrowWidth),
            newY + (risePercent2 * arrowWidth)
        );
        context.lineTo(
            targetX - (runPercent * (targetSize + (arrowWidth / 2))),
            targetY - (risePercent * (targetSize + (arrowWidth / 2)))
        );
        context.lineTo(
            newX - (runPercent2 * arrowWidth),
            newY - (risePercent2 * arrowWidth)
        );

        context.strokeStyle = color;
        context.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be that IE has caught Chrome in terms of at least one aspect of performance :-)

However, both IE10 and Chrome can use the GPU to accelerate rendering.  Ensure that you have GPU support either enabled or disabled for both platforms when performing your tests

http://apmsystems.com/blog/?p=197

http://www.windowsvalley.com/how-to-enable-gpu-acceleration-or-gpu-rendering-in-google-chrome-8-or-higher/

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but it seems i have hardware acceleration enabled in both!